# Add an eventlistener for when div text-content area is filled

Tags: javascript

I have a form and once it submits, it does some processing and then fills a specified div class with the output.

I was wondering how to add an eventlistener to check when that div has texted has fill in and when it is empty.

Comment: Why don't you just handle the submit accordingly?

Comment: give us the code you use already and it shouldn't be too difficult.  probably just the success callback from your AJAX.

Comment: You can have an event that checks for DOMChange.. but that is not supported by all browsers I believe.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind a custom event and then trigger it when changing the html (text) of the div.

```
$("#myDiv").bind("htmlChange", function()
{
    //Check if html is empty or has some kind of input you're looking for
});
```

And when changing the HTML just

```
$("#myDiv").html("New text").trigger("htmlChange");
```

Comment: Why not just call the function that you are triggering when you update the HTML? No need for an eventlistener.

Comment: Well, actually we can also say that a DIV is not changing by user at any cause, hence it is changing by code only. So he can just put the code he needs where he changes the DIV's content.. or have a function to deal with it